# Configure jetty 8 to log different application logs to different files

Tags: logging, configuration, jetty

I am trying to start two different applications in jetty and my server logs current rollover configuration is to route the logs is as below.

```
<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
      <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
      <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

How can I change it to work with application specific routing, something like

```
<Configure id="Application">
```

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: [Jetty 8 was declared EOL (End of Life) in 2014](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading to something more recent/stable.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Lets say it is more complicated than that, As of now I had to use jetty 8, no other option.

Answer (score 1):

RolloverFileOutputStream is for capturing the console SYSOUT / SYSERR to a file that has daily rollover.

You cannot split up logs using that layer.

Upgrade to a non EOL version of Jetty and you can use a modern logging layer (such as slf4j with logback, utilizing a sifting setup based on the application context) to accomplish this.